# Warning for render method that should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I render when there is an alert that's pulled from the state. Currently the alert dispatches and displays but i'm getting the following error and i'm not sure how I would rework this component to comply.

**Error:**
`Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.`

```
const Alerts = ({ alerts }) =>
  alerts !== null &&
  alerts.length > 0 &&
  alerts.map((alert) =>
    notification[`${alert.type}`]({
      key: `${alert.id}`,
      message: `${alert.title}`,
      description: `${alert.message}`,
    })
  );
```

Comment: Could you give more context to this? What does notification object has?

Comment: It's the notification component from the antd library: https://ant.design/components/notification/

Comment: Consider reading antd docs carefully about notification component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the render function should be pure and without side-effects. Remember, the *entire* function body of a functional component ***is*** the render function. Use an `useEffect` hook to issue side-effects.

Also, instead of using array::map, use array::forEach as that is the intended array function to issue side-effect on an array.

Remember to explicitly return `null` from the function to indicate to react there is nothing to render.

```
const Alerts = ({ alerts }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (alerts) {
      alerts.forEach(alert => {
        notification[alert.type]({
          key: alert.id,
          message: alert.title,
          description: alert.message,
        })
      })
    }
  }, [alerts]);

  return null;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Drew. This nailed it!

Comment: So while this worked on the login page, it doesnt appear to work when a user is logged in. For whatever reason im receiving `TypeError: antd__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.notification[alert.type] is not a function`. Does this have anything to do with no return statement within the use effect?

Comment: I don't think so. The return function of the `useEffect` hook is just a cleanup function. This error appears to be saying that at somepoint `notification[alert.type]` isn't a function, or isn't defined, and thus can't be invoked. You could try placing a null check on it, i.e. `notification[alert.type] && notification[alert.type](config)` or `notification[alert.type]?.(config)`. If that doesn't quite get it then I would try logging in the effect the values of `alerts` and in the forEach callback `notification[alert.type]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to return an array of `ReactElement`s that way, try this:

```
const Alerts = ({ alerts }) => {
  if(alerts !== null &&
  alerts.length > 0) {
  return 
    (<>
    {alerts.map(({type, id, title, message}) =>
      notification[type]({
        key: `${id}`,
        message: `${title}`,
        description: `${message}`,
    })}
    </>)} else { return null }
  });
```

Comment: I tried that and continued to receive the same error

Comment: Did you check that `notification[type]()` returns a ReactElement?